# Memory leak in my iOS apps

Tags: ios

I'm currently fixing the memory leaks that cause too many crashes to my iPhone app...

In the appDelegate, I use the following code to init the tabbarcontroller. Is that a good way to do so, especially the "homeNavigationController.tabBarItem init" part ? (tabBarController is a property and is released within the dealloc method).

```
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

// HomeTab view
HomeTabViewController *home = [[HomeTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeTabViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:home];
[homeNavigationController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"home", @"home") image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] tag:1];
[localControllersArray addObject:homeNavigationController];
[homeNavigationController release];
[home release];

// My 3 others controllers
...
// End 3 other controllers

tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[localControllersArray release];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
[homeNavigationController.tabBarItem initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"home", @"home") image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] tag:1];
```

is a leak. You should change it to:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"home", @"home") image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"] tag:1];
homeNavigationController.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
[tabBarItem release]; // If you are not using ARC.
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is a leak?

Comment: Wait, this isn't a leak. But where are you allocating the tabBarItem? Can't find it in your code.

Comment: Is that a leak because of the "init" without any "release"?

Comment: Again: Where are you allocating the tabBarItem?

Comment: General advise: Never use alloc and init in separate places. If you have only an alloc or an init there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the alloc-autorelease pattern

```
 [[[class alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This makes sure that release will always be called.  If I need the object to stick around, I assign it to a property with retain set or pass it to a method that retains.

This is described in Google's iOS guidelines:

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml#Prefer_To_autorelease_At_Time_of_Creation

Comment: I though it was better not to use autorelease object (I do not know why though...).

Comment: The iOS framework uses autorelease all of the time.  It is a tiny bit slower because the pool needs to deal with it instead of a simple release call -- if you end up having performance problems in an area, and find that there are excessive pool releases (of autoreleased objects), then you can optimize it later.  In the meantime, not using autorelease is very error prone, and you are likely to have much worse problems.